# IsDigit() in c reading char as digit in C

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to check if a char is upper case, lower case or a digit without using the library functions. I wrote my own functions but when I enter a character, my IsDigit() returns true and says that it is a digit rather than saying it is not.

I can't seem to find out where the bug is in my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int isLower(char ch) 
{
   if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') 
   {
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
}
int isUpper(char ch)
{
    if(ch>='A' && ch<='Z')
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
int isDigit(char ch)
{
    if(ch>=0 && ch <=47876)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
   char ch='L';




   if(isLower(ch))
   {
       printf("%c is lower case.\n", ch);
   }
   else
   {
        printf("%c is not lower case.\n",ch);
   }

   if(isUpper(ch))
   {
       printf("%c is upper case.\n",ch);
   }
   else{
        printf("%c is not upper case.\n", ch);
   }


   if(isDigit(ch))
   {
       printf("%c is a digit.\n",ch);
   }
   else{
       printf("%c is not a digit.\n",ch);
   }

   return (0);
  }
Output:
d is lower case.
d is not upper case.
d is a digit.
```

Comment: How did you come up with the test `if(ch>=0 && ch <=47876)`?

Comment: I wasn't sure of the range of numbers. I now know

Comment: (well heavens-to-Betsie -- don't guess...)

Comment: @SuneetSingh But did you get 47876 from somewhere or derive it from something? It's such a strange number (not a power of 2 or the same plus-or-minus 1) so I'm very interested. It's maddening! I must know!

Comment: As a general hint: `if(x) { return true; } else { return false; }` is kind of an antipattern. Its the same as just `return x;`

Comment: Note that there are character sets (ahem: [EBCDIC](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)) for which `ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'` will not give the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Return the result of the test directly and use the same style as you did with the letters.

```cpp
int isDigit(char ch)
{
    return (ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9');
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to make a truly useful answer out of it.

Comment: Note that the parentheses in the `return` statement are entirely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem is in your implementation of isDigit() function**. There are only 10 digits 0-9 (0 and 9 inclusive). See the ascii table http://www.asciitable.com/ to understand why your code was behaving incorrectly. So I think the implementation should be like (I am correcting you example):

```c
int isDigit(char ch)
{
    if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now, since you were trying to compare specifically with 47876 then I would like to know your thoughts on that. Thanks. Happy programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your isdigit() check. 
Even though isdigit() takes an integer as an argument, the character is passed to the function. Internally, the character is converted to its ASCII value for the check.

logic: for non-numeric argument isdigit() will return 0 and for numeric argument will return non-zero unsigned integer

Modification:

```
if (isdigit( ch ) == 0)  
     return False; 
 else       
    return True;
```

Comment: The way you wrote it it is an endless recursion. You probably mean `std::isdigit`?? Adding namespace prefixes helps. Also that convoluted `if(x) return true; else return false;`

Comment: @churill the tag is marked here as C, so i write this answer w.r.t to C. 
there is no endless recursion in C.

Comment: The question is also (and was originally) tagged C++ which leads to some ambiguity, so calling the C-function may be fine, agreed. But Why should there be no endless recursion in C?

Comment: @churill can you pls elaborate more on endless recursion, i am not aware of C++ but as language logic, this doesn't seem to me endless recursion. correct me on this if am wrong :)

Comment: In the original version of your answer the first think `isDigit` did was to call `isDigit` e.g. itself. You can image the rest.

Comment: @churill as per the above code block posted by Suneet Singh, he just want to call the function once. So as soon as the variable passed to isdigit() function will compare only once and will return 0 or non-zero unsigned integer(depend on what argument you pass).

Hope you understood the woking. 

and how about to upvote which you recently downvote :)

Comment: isDigit was written mistakenly, i have modified this as soon as I saw that. but in the written comment, it was mentioned as isdigit() initially.

Comment: Thats why I mentioned it int he first place, agreed, that it's an ok answer now  :)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check,

1. The size of your used data type (e.g.: char - Sizeof char is 1 byte) and whether signed or unsigned data type.
2. return type of your function.

Reason for saying is, 
In your code, two minor issues.

1. return type is **int** but you are returning either true/false. But it should be a value.
2. Size of char is 1 byte (0-255 bits). since you had declared char (signed by default), the bit range from (-128 - 0 - 127). but you are checking the value in if condition is **47876**

   ```
   int isDigit(char ch)
   {
       if(ch>=0 && ch <=47876)     // **Reason for checking the value upto 47876?**
       {
          return true;       // return value should be integer value.
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```